# How to have a link which gets data via ajax, then changes to allow the data to be hidden?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using asp mvc 2 and I have a page which has some data on, and I have a link which will execute an ajax request to get some data and post it to a div on the page.

once I have the data I'd like something to become visible which I could click to toggle the visibility of the div containing the data, so the user could show/hide this extra information, but I don't want the original link to be visible anymore.

I don't mind if the original link changes what it does so that say before the data is loaded it says 'Show Data' then once it is loaded it then changes to 'Hide Data' and if it is hidden it changes to 'Show Data' again and if it is clicked again then it just show the div again (although reloading the data from the ajax call would not be the end of the world)

My web-fu and jQuery-fu are not strong.  How can I go about getting what I want?  I've banged my head against this wall without a really satisfactory resolution for a day or so now and feel like I must be missing something in my understanding of how things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
<a href="#" id="myToggler">Show</a>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myToggler').click(function() {
        var link = $(this);
        var content = $('#myDiv');
        if(!content.data('isLoaded')) {
            content.load('path/to/something', function() {
                content.data('isLoaded', true);
            });
        }
        content.toggle(function() {
            if(content.is(':visible')) {
                link.text('Hide');
            } else {
                link.text('Show');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

### Update

You indicated that you would have many content areas with toggle links on a single page, so a minor change to the HTML and the script the above should do the trick:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="toggler">Show</a>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.toggler').click(function() {
        var link = $(this);
        var parent = link.parent('.content-wrapper');
        var content = parent.find('.content');
        if(!content.data('isLoaded')) {
            content.load('path/to/something', function() {
                content.data('isLoaded', true);
            });
        }
        content.toggle(function() {
            if(content.is(':visible')) {
                link.text('Hide');
            } else {
                link.text('Show');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks I'll try and adapt this.  i should probably have said that I have several of these elements on the page so do not have fixed ids as the ids are generated from the data in the view.  They all have the same class though, if that helps.  Can I modify the function to use the dynamic ids?

Comment: @SamHolder Please see the updates to my answer. If you have any more questions, I'd be happy to answer them.

Comment: thanks a lot this is almost perfect.  I just needed to make sure that when I loaded the data the content was hidden so the first toggle would show it.  Thanks I learnt a lot from that.